# Looping through an object to add elements to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with a button, when the button is pressed, a group of form elements are added to the page. There will be like 5-10 of these buttons eventually, so I Thought it best to add them programmatically through an array or something similar.

There is an object, containing objects for the elements & their properties e.g. type/name/class etc. But I am just deciding on what to add with various If elements, and I don't feel it's really efficient at all - i hope this isn't too subjective of a question. Is there anything like switch that would make it that much better?

```
for(var input in addUserElements) {
    var obj = addUserElements[input];
    for(var property in obj) {
        if(obj[property] == 'text' && property == 'type' || obj[property] == 'email' && property == 'type' || obj[property] == 'number' && property == 'type' || obj[property] == 'password' && property == 'type') {
            $('.working-area').append('<input type="' + obj["type"] + '" name="' + obj["name"] + '" class="' + obj["class"] + '" placeholder="' + obj["placeholder"] + '" />');
        }
        if(obj[property] == 'textarea') {
            $('.working-area').append('<textarea name="' + obj["name"] + '" class="' + obj["class"] + '" placeholder="' + obj["placeholder"] + '"></textarea>');
        }
        if(obj[property] == 'button') {
            $('.working-area').append('<button name="' + obj["name"] + '" class="' + obj["class"] + '">' + obj["text"] + '</button>');
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q962T/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery allows you to create elements by passing an object like this:

```
$('body').html($('<div />', {class: 'spinner'}));
```

So you can do:

```
if(obj[property] == 'text' && property == 'type' || obj[property] == 'email' && property == 'type' || obj[property] == 'number' && property == 'type' || obj[property] == 'password' && property == 'type') {
    $("<input />", obj).appendTo('.working-area');
}
if(obj[property] == 'textarea') {
    $("<textarea />", obj).appendTo('.working-area');
}
if(obj[property] == 'button') {
    $("<button />", obj).appendTo('.working-area');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(obj[property] == 'text' && property == 'type' || obj[property] == 'email' && property == 'type' || obj[property] == 'number' && property == 'type' || obj[property] == 'password' && property == 'type') {
    $("<input />", obj).appendTo('.working-area');
}
if(obj[property] == 'textarea') {
    $("<textarea />", obj).appendTo('.working-area');
}
if(obj[property] == 'button') {
    $("<button />", obj).appendTo('.working-area');
}
```